# Iterating Through a List and Conditionally Setting a Member - Comparison Of Approaches

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, iteration

I have a requirement to iterate through a list, and conditionally set a data item against each item in the collection:

Using the standard `foreach` iterator, this is trivial:

```
//standard iteration
foreach (LogFileDataItem lfd in logFileData)
{
    if (lfd.FileName.Equals(currentLine, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        lfd.SQLScriptExecuted = true;
    }
}
```

But it got me into thinking that this was an ideal opportunity to explore LINQ, so I refactored to above to:

```
foreach (LogFileDataItem lfd in 
         from logFileDataItem in logFileData
         where logFileDataItem.FileName.Equals(currentLine, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
         select logFileDataItem)
{
    lfd.SQLScriptExecuted = true;
}
```

Which, of course can be refactored into a lambda expression:

```
foreach (LogFileDataItem lfd in logFileData.Where(item => item.FileName.Equals(currentLine, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                           .Select(item => item))
{
    lfd.SQLScriptExecuted = true;
}
```

So my question really is really, how different are they? Do any offer a significant advantage over any other?

Comment: The `Select(item => item)` in your 3rd piece of code (the one with the lambda) is totally useless ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can get rid of the "Select(item => item)" bit from the lambda version (as indeed the C# compiler would have done):

```
foreach (LogFileDataItem lfd in logFileData.Where(item => 
    item.FileName.Equals(currentLine, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

But basically, yes - they're all doing the same thing. I'd consider separating out the query from the foreach loop:

```
var relevantLogItems = logFileData.Where(...);
foreach (var lfd in relevantLogItems)
{
    ...
}
```

but again that won't actually change what occurs.

Comment: +1 Correct. Perhaps, the LINQ version has a bit more overhead than the foreach loop, but the difference is definitely negligible and in term of results they're exactly the same. It's basically a coding style choice IMO